# UIImagePickerController Video countdown timer

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the `UIImagePickerController` to let the user record video. The duration is limited to 10 seconds. I want to display a countdown in the corner while they are recording though so they know how long they have left. I am able to add this using the `cameraOverlayView` property. But I can't find anyway to get a call when they hit the record button (so that I can start my timer to update my countdown).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you got the solution. i m facing same issue